# How to dynamically add and remove fields for more than one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, field

Is there an easier way in JQuery to dynamically add and remove fields for more than one field within the same form?  I have two form elements in the same form that I'd like to have the ability to add and remove blank fields to.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    Email<g:field type="email" name="Email" class="form-control" required="" value="" aria-labelledby="Email-label"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">  
    Fax<g:field type="tel" name="Fax" class="form-control" required="true" value="" aria-labelledby="Fax-label"/>
</div>
```

I have cobbled together this javascript piece from several different places and it works just fine for the first field, but when I try to duplicate it for the second one it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function (e) {
        $("#submitterEmail").append('<div><input type="text" name="submitterEmail[]"><button class="delete">Delete</button></div>');
    });

$("body").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    $(this).parent("div").remove();
});
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete the fields from the DOM?

Comment: I'd like to have the ability to add and delete blank fields for each one.

Comment: I've been looking around for examples and I think I might like this one the best -- http://voidtricks.com/jquery-add-remove-input-fields/ - I'd like to be able to do something similar for multiples fields with the div classes I have in place in my post...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the JavaScript based on the HTML you have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").on("click", function(){
        $("#container").append(
            "<div class='col-sm-3'><g:field>Another field <button class='delete'>Delete</button></div>"
        );
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/suqecura/1/edit)

Comment: excellent I will try that.  In theory will that work for multiple fields if you just match up the correct id's and values?

Comment: You don't need to match up the IDs since the CSS selector that jQuery uses is starting from the actual button that was clicked (and then going up two levels to find the DIV to delete)

Comment: do I need to repeat the entire piece for the other field, or just call the button again?

Comment: @ry1633 I am not sure what you mean.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Do I need to repeat the entire code to apply it to the second field?

Comment: @ry1633 No, as long as each field has the same mark-up

Comment: when I try it, the add button doesn't work.  It just kicks me back to the top.